# Rails 4 turbolinks page:load with JS

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have the following basic JavaScript ( CoffeeScript ) in my app

```
window.onload = ->
  menu = document.getElementById("menu")
  wrapper = document.getElementById("wrapper")
  toggleMenu = false

  menu.onclick = ->
    if toggleMenu is false
      wrapper.style.left = "278px"
      toggleMenu = true
    else
      wrapper.style.left = "0px"
      toggleMenu = false
```

When you click on something with turbolinks, it stops working.

I found this solution on SO, but don't know how to implement it in JavaScript:

```
$(document).on('page:change', function () {
  // Actions to do
});
```

I did try document.onchange with no success.
What would be the pure JavaScript solution for this?

Comment: `document.addEventListener('load', function(){...});`??

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
document.addEventListener('page:change', function(){
  console.log('called')
});

# page reloaded, no clicks yet
=> called
# click turbolinks link
=> called
```